# PivotTable FormatConditions ScopeType is causing 1004

Tags: excel, vba

A 1004 error occurs at the very end of the Sub, when trying to set the ScopeType. I want the formatcondition to apply to all active rows in the current column, so I thought this would do it.

```
    Sub CreatePivot()
        ' Define RngTarget and RngSource as Range type variables
        Dim RngTarget As Range
        Dim RngSource As Range
        Dim intLastCol As Integer
        Dim intCntrCol As Integer
        Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim pt As PivotTable
        Dim cf As FormatCondition

        Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        ws2.Cells.Clear

        ' RngTarget is where the PivotTable will be created (ie: Sheet2, Cell B3)
        Set RngTarget = ws2.Range("B3")
        'Set RngTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B3")

        ' RngSource defines the Range that will be used to create the PivotTable
        ' ActiveWorkbook = The currently opened Workbook
        ' ActiveSheet = The currectly opened sheet
        ' UsedRange = The Range of cells with active data in them
        Set RngSource = ws1.UsedRange
        'Set RngSource = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

        ' Select the Range
        ws1.Select
        RngSource.Select

        ' Copy the Range into the clipboard
        RngSource.Copy

        ' Create a new PivotTable using the RngSource defined above,
        ' in Excel format,
        ' placed at the RngTarget location,
        ' And name it PivotB3 just for reference if needed
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, RngSource).CreatePivotTable RngTarget, "PivotB3"
        Set pt = RngTarget.PivotTable

        ' Get the last used column from the data table
        intLastCol = RngSource.Columns(RngSource.Columns.Count).Column

        ' Select the Pivot table so we can apply the conditional formats
        pt.PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True

        For intCntrCol = 3 To intLastCol
            ws2.Select
            ws2.Cells(4, intCntrCol).Select ' Select the current Sum column
            Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=5000" ' Set conditional format to less than 5000
            Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority ' Take priority over any other formats
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font ' Use the Font property for the next operations
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1 ' Set it to the default (if it does not meet the condition)
                .TintAndShade = 0 ' Same as above
            End With
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535 ' Set the background color to Yellow
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
            Selection.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlFieldsScope ' Apply the format to all rows that match "Sum of xxxx"
        Next intCntrCol
    End Sub
```

Comment: hmmm ... so I guess nobody has any ideas for this one?

Answer (score -1):

Based on you [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369816/pivottable-woes) I propose this method for applying your formatting:

```
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
With ws2.UsedRange
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=5000" ' Set conditional format to less than 5000
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority ' Take priority over any other formats
    With .FormatConditions(1).Font ' Use the Font property for the next operations
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1 ' Set it to the default (if it does not meet the condition)
        .TintAndShade = 0 ' Same as above
    End With
    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535 ' Set the background color to Yellow
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
```