# Pivottable woes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

It seems like all of the examples from other people are just like what I already have in my code. But in my case, nothing resolves the problem. So here is the complete code along with a break to show where I am having a problem:

```
    Sub CreatePivot()
        ' Define RngTarget and RngSource as Range type variables
        Dim RngTarget As Range
        Dim RngSource As Range
        Dim intLastCol As Integer
        Dim intLCPivot As Integer
        Dim intLRPivot As Integer
        Dim intCntrCol As Integer
        Dim intX, intY As Integer
        Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim pt As PivotTable
        Dim cf As FormatCondition

        Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        ws2.Cells.Clear

        ' RngTarget is where the PivotTable will be created (ie: Sheet2, Cell B3)
        Set RngTarget = ws2.Range("B3")

        ' RngSource defines the Range that will be used to create the PivotTable
        Set RngSource = ws1.UsedRange

        ' Select the Range
        ws1.Select  ' Not sure why this is needed, but 1004 if omitted
        RngSource.Select

        ' Copy the Range into the clipboard
        RngSource.Copy

        ' Create a new PivotTable using the RngSource defined above
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, RngSource).CreatePivotTable RngTarget, "PivotB3"
        Set pt = RngTarget.PivotTable

    '' This is where the the problem is. After the pivottable is created, if I look at sheet2, I see
    '' only the wizard. Like this: http://wikisend.com/download/617932/ptwizard.jpg
    '' I need to have all of the fields automatically selected to be included in
    '' the report. I haven't been able to test anything beyond this, although it compiles without
    '' a problem.

        ' Get the last col and row from the pivottable
        intLCPivot = pt.DataBodyRange.Columns(pt.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Column
        intLRPivot = pt.DataBodyRange.Rows(pt.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count).Row

        ' Get the last used column from the data table
        intLastCol = RngSource.Columns(RngSource.Columns.Count).Column

        ' Select the Pivot table so we can apply the conditional formats
        pt.PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True

    '' This also causes an error. I need to be able to get the conditional format from Sheet1:B3 and apply it
    '' to all Data cells in the PivotTable Report, instead of hardcoding the format like it is now.

        'cf = ws1.Range("B3").FormatCondition

        ws2.Select
        For intX = 1 To intLCPivot
            For intY = 1 To intLRPivot
                ws2.Cells(4, intCntrCol).Select ' Select the current Sum column
                Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=5000" ' Set conditional format to less than 5000
                Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority ' Take priority over any other formats
                With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font ' Use the Font property for the next operations
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1 ' Set it to the default (if it does not meet the condition)
                    .TintAndShade = 0 ' Same as above
                End With
                With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 65535 ' Set the background color to Yellow
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
                'Selection.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlFieldsScope ' Apply the format to all rows that match "Sum of xxxx"
            Next intY
        Next intX
    End Sub
```

Comment: It seems to error because you haven't added any fields to the pivot table. It's blank at this stage. How are you adding them?

Comment: Well, that's the problem. I haven't been able to figure out how to add them. I mean, I can add them if I hardcode all of the field names and do them with " ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotB3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotB3").PivotFields("CUST_COUNT"), "Sum of CUST_COUNT", xlSum", but as the data source table is constantly changing, I will not know the names of the fields to add. So I am trying to find out how to add all available fields to the report.

Comment: If you know where they came from you could use these titles in the first row... I'm looking now for a better solution.

Comment: `ws1.Select` is needed because of the following line `rngSource.Select` (you can only select a range on the active worksheet). Incidentally, both of those lines can be removed with no effect on performance because you can do `RngSource.Copy` without Selecting the Range object, and without being on the range's worksheet..

Comment: Thank you David. I've fixed those. I appreciate the suggestion. I'll get the hang of this eventually. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this to your script in place of the error'd lines you'll get all their names and add then to the pivot:

```
For Each p In pt.PivotFields
    Debug.Print p.Name
    pt.AddDataField p,,xlSum
Next
```

I'm sure this will get you over the  line. :)

Comment: This will add all of them to the pivot also.

Comment: Thank you! I actually went with your first idea about just looking at the datasource and now all the fields are added! That is such a huge relief! Now it looks like my idea for getting the usedrange in in the pivottable report didn't work out. It's getting the last column right (probably a fluke), but the last row is the last row from the source, not the resulting table. The nested FOR-NEXT loop works great! It's just setting the CF for too many rows. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I'm looking into that now but if you open another question about conditional formatting a pivot chart it will help other users if they need it.

Comment: With that you don't need a loop.

Comment: @user Saw this and added my thoughts. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16370207/1685810