# Conditional formatting a pivottable report

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I need to get the pre-assigned conditional format from Sheet1:B3 and apply it to all used cells in a generated PivotTable report. So there are two parts that I am having a problem with. First would be finding out the usedrange for the report, and the second is getting the format and applying it to those cells. The 3 spots with errors are marked with '' DOES NOT WORK

```
    Sub CreatePivot()
        ' Define RngTarget and RngSource as Range type variables
        Dim RngTarget As Range
        Dim RngSource As Range
        Dim intLastCol As Integer
        Dim intLCPivot As Integer
        Dim intLRPivot As Integer
        Dim intCntrCol As Integer
        Dim intX, intY As Integer
        Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim pt As PivotTable
        Dim strHeader As String
        Dim cf As FormatCondition

        Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        ws2.Cells.Clear

        ' RngTarget is where the PivotTable will be created (ie: Sheet2, Cell B3)
        Set RngTarget = ws2.Range("B3")
        'Set RngTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B3")

        ' RngSource defines the Range that will be used to create the PivotTable
        ' ActiveWorkbook = The currently opened Workbook
        ' ActiveSheet = The currectly opened sheet
        ' UsedRange = The Range of cells with active data in them
        Set RngSource = ws1.UsedRange

        ' Copy the Range into the clipboard
        RngSource.Copy

        ' Create a new PivotTable using the RngSource defined above,
        ' in Excel format,
        ' placed at the RngTarget location,
        ' And name it PivotB3 just for reference if needed
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, RngSource).CreatePivotTable RngTarget, "PivotB3"
        Set pt = RngTarget.PivotTable

        ' Get the last used column from the data table
        intLastCol = RngSource.Columns(RngSource.Columns.Count).Column

        ' Add all columns to the report
        ws2.Select
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotB3").PivotFields("RECORDTYPE")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        For intX = 3 To intLastCol
            strHeader = ws1.Cells(3, intX).Value
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotB3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotB3").PivotFields(strHeader), "Sum of " & strHeader, xlSum
        Next intX

    '' DOES NOT WORK
        ' Get the last used row and column from the generated pivottable report so that conditional formatting
        ' can be applied to each used cell
        intLCPivot = pt.DataBodyRange.Columns(pt.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Column
        intLRPivot = pt.DataBodyRange.Rows(pt.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count).Row

        ' Select the Pivot table so we can apply the conditional formats
        pt.PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True

    '' DOES NOT WORK
        ' Get the conditional format from Sheet1:B3 and apply it to all used cells in the pivottable
        'cf = ws1.Range("B3").FormatCondition

        ws2.Select
        For intX = 2 To intLCPivot
            For intY = 5 To intLRPivot
                ws2.Cells(intY, intX).Select ' Select the current Sum column
    '' DOES NOT WORK
                'Selection.FormatConditions.Add cf

                Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=5000" ' Set conditional format to less than 5000
                Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority ' Take priority over any other formats
                With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font ' Use the Font property for the next operations
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1 ' Set it to the default (if it does not meet the condition)
                    .TintAndShade = 0 ' Same as above
                End With
                With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 65535 ' Set the background color to Yellow
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
            Next intY
        Next intX
    End Sub
```

Comment: FYI your variables are not being declared correctly.  For example, `Dim intX, intY As Integer` only declares `intY As Integer`.  `intX` is unspecified, so it will be type `Variant`.  Likewise with the next line `Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet` where only `ws2` is declared a Worksheet variable.  Cheers.

Comment: oops! Thanks David. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369816/pivottable-woes) I propose this method for applying your formatting:

```
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
With ws2.UsedRange
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=5000" ' Set conditional format to less than 5000
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority ' Take priority over any other formats
    With .FormatConditions(1).Font ' Use the Font property for the next operations
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1 ' Set it to the default (if it does not meet the condition)
        .TintAndShade = 0 ' Same as above
    End With
    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535 ' Set the background color to Yellow
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

**Based on comment** if you have a cell that has the conditional formatting copy it over:

```
ws1.[B3].Copy
ws2.UsedRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

**Also** if you need to remove the headers this will be difficult but if the number of headers and first columns in known the `offset` method will help:

```
With ws2.UsedRange
    Dim c1 As Range, c2 As Range
    Set c1 = .Cells(1).Offset(2, 1) '<~~ 2 rows down and 1 column in
    Set c2 = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Offset(-1) '<~~ 1 row up
End With

With ws2.Range(c1, c2)
    '<~~ add conditions here
end with
```

Comment: Ok, that's much cleaner than the nested FOR-NEXT loops. The only problem though is that the actual formula could change. The correct formula will always be in Sheet1:B3. But other than that, I definitely like this method of assignment a lot better.

Comment: the limit value is in b3? the you can change `=5000` to `"=" & ws1.[B3]`

Comment: Well, not the limit value. But B3 will have the same conditional format that should be applied to the pivottable cells. So B3 would have the formula, font settings, pattern and color.'

Comment: ahhhh ... excellent! Ok, one last final little nitpicky thing ... the "usedrange" includes the headers so the background is wrong. Is there a quick way to change that or should I get the first and last row and column then redefine the range with the listheaderrows?

Comment: Actually, the pastespecial didn't work out. It took away the results of the report and overwrote them with just the value in B3.

Comment: should've been `xlPasteFormats`

Comment: Yep! That fixed that. :) I'll go ahead and just redefine the range to remove the header rows. You've helped so much already I don't want to put you out any longer. Thank you so very much! You have been an incredible help!

Comment: too late! :) glad I can to help

Comment: Yep! I like your code better. I had forgotten about the column that needed to be taken out. Thanks again! This project is now done! *phew*